# How to get id from one page to another page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have a page to get some data from a user, this data will save in `first_forms` table, but I have other fields in the table for next page and they are null.

this is `first_forms` table :

[image: first_forms table]

In this table, `project_name`, `customer_name`, `buyer`, `response`, `model` will be saved in the first step in the first page `choose.blade.php`

This is store function in the controller:

```
FirstForm::create([
   'model' => $request['model'],
   'project_name' => $request['project_name'],
   'customer_name' => $request['customer_name'],
   'buyer' => $request['buyer'],
   'response' => $request['response'],
]);
return view('Form2.firstForm');
```

As you can see other fields in `first_forms` table will be null. After this user redirect to next page `firstForm`. Now in this page users have to complete other fields like: `airflow`, `tcp`, `compress_number`, etc. I want when user click on submit in this page, new fields in this page save in the previous row in `first_forms` table who complete in the previous page, how can I do this?

I think I have to get the id of who completes he previous page and update row with new fields in a new page, but I don't know how I can get the id and update row. Primary key is `id`.

This is `first_forms` table when user complete first page :

[image: first_forms table]

This is the data of who completed the first page. On the next page, those fields are null, have to be complete in this row.

Comment: can you share your Models codes?

Comment: in models only fillable have been set

Comment: have any relations?

Comment: no, need to relation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can simply check that

```
$first = FirstForm::create([
  'model' => $request['model'],
  'project_name' => $request['project_name'],
  'customer_name' => $request['customer_name'],
  'buyer' => $request['buyer'],
  'response' => $request['response'],
]);

//Below line will re-retrieve the record along with primary key which is `id`
$first = $first->fresh();

return view('Form2.firstForm',compact('first'));
```

*In view you can access inserted data like `$first->id` Now place your id in a hidden field of the nextform and update your record according to that id. You can even show the previously inserted record in readonly fields of the nextform*

**In your nextform view**

```
<input type="hidden" name="update_id" value="{{ $first->id ?? '' }}" />
```

When you submit the nextform with all other fields, you will get the hidden id as well. So again in your controller method you will do something like

```
FirstForm::where('id',request('update_id'))->update([
   //here goes your other fields of the nextform
]);
```